# Sum specific row values from one column that are referenced from another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looked a bit for this info but I'm stuck.

let's say I have two columns. I have to find top largest values from one column and sum the corresponding row values from the other column.

To find the values and average the result, I'm using the following formula (where c19 is the number of items to retrieve): +AVERAGE(LARGE('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!B1:B1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19))))

What I want now, is to retrieve and sum the matching row values from the second column. I can't seem to find a way to nest that formula.

Something like this?

Sumif

Range - AVERAGE(LARGE('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!B1:B1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19))))

Criteria - ?????

Sum_range - ('3.Tabela_DC_Marca'!C1:C1500;ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&C19)

Please see my file here, because it's hard to explain:
[File DEMO](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ccba42b9116a9cbdcf8549e0d0c35bcd20201022102600/f5f0d7ef72badd674bc44c73241a6f6120201022102600/9f4da7)

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working (if I understand your requirements correctly).

=IF(A1=MAX(A:A),A1+B1,"Not max")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hogaw.png)

Comment: didn't quite understand your answer. just edited my post to include a DEMO file if you can help with the correct formula. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Data in attached WB are quit confusing, so to fix the issue I've used sample data set, address OP issue, " I have two columns. I have to find top largest values from one column and sum the corresponding row values from the other column."*

[image]

- Array (CSE) Formula in cell H42:

  ```
  {=SUM(VLOOKUP(MAX($G$34:$G$40), $G$34:$I$40, {2,3}, FALSE))}
  ```

**N.B.**

- For better understanding I've used 3 Columns instead of 2.
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: thank you, but I did solve it without array. Now i'm struggling to find the SMALL xx values :) =+SUMIF('sheet'!C1:C1500;">="&LARGE('sheet'!C1:C1500;C19);'sheet'!AI1:AI1500)

Comment: @PedroRocha,,, what you are trying gets the SUM of all values are in A1:A1500, equals to the LARGEST value in C1:C1500,,, unfortunately it doesn't addresses your question,,, **I have to find top largest values from one column and sum the corresponding row values from the other column**. If you try your formula on my data set, in column G `10` is the LARGEST and for column B or even in B & C you get `20`,,, BUT those 10s are not the corresponding Row values,,, The LARGEST in column G  is `10` in cell  G40, has two corresponding values in ROW, are in cells H40 and I40 !!